# Angular Repeat - Dynamic properties

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a really basic ng-repeat of data in a table:

```
$scope.data = [ {
    version: 1,
    ID: 78,
    name: "Bulk 61",
    createdBy: "Master",
    email: "email@email.com",
    city: "New York",
    state: "New York",
    country: "Canada",
    address: "123 street road",
    type: "Something",
  },
  {
    version: 2,
    ID: 4,
    name: "Bulk 1221",
    createdBy: "Master22",
    email: "ema2il@email.com",
    city: "New York22",
    state: "New Yor22k",
    country: "Canada2",
    address: "123 str22eet road",
    type: "Somet2hing",
  }
];
```

Thing is, I have no idea what the object properties will be because I will receive the property names in another object:

```
  $scope.properties = [
    "name",
    "type",
    "ID",
    "country",
    "email"
  ];
```

So, in reality, depending on the properties I receive, it could be `item.country` instead of `item.name`

So if I build the table in the view, it would look like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="property in properties">{{property}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
    <td>{{item.property[0]}}</td>
    <td>{{item.property[1]}}</td>
    <td>{{item.property[2]}}</td>
    <td>{{item.property[3]}}</td>
    <td>{{item.property[4]}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to do what I want? Obviously if I know the property name, it's easy to put it in the view, but in this case, it's dependent on what I receive from the `properties` object.

I created a plnkr to demonstrate what I want to achieve : http://plnkr.co/edit/LImqZuLzcvKsbHUEOOrX?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just setup a second repeater to iterate the property names and use bracket notation:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data">
  <td ng-repeat="prop in properties">{{item[prop]}}</td>
</tr>
```

You probably want to check to see if the property name exists in the currently iterated `item`